# most significant digit in an repetitive list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a piece of code which requires a certain list containing most significant digit for but problem occurs while using `.index()`
method

I've tried `.index()` and it returns same index for repetitive digits

ie `num=[4,9,9,9,3,3,5,5,3]`
and it returns index by doing iterations as

`[0,1,1,1,4,4,6,6,4]`

```
out = []
for number in range(len(num)):
    out.append(num.index(number))
```

expected output is "considered repetitiveness"

```
[0,1,1,1,4,4,6,6,8]  # repeated last index fixed
```

Comment: I do not see the link between the concept of most significant digit and a list of integers (the digits?).

Comment: `.index()` returns the *first* index of the given argument, always considering the whole list

Comment: How does 8 comes in the last place? I cannot follow what logic is being used to create the output

Comment: 8 is the index of the third occurance of 4

Comment: its confusing for me too since ive been triying it for past 4 hrs

Comment: The description of the problem is still confusing. "8 is the index of the third occurance of 4", but the input list doesn't contain the number 4.

Comment: @Anshul how do you define *most significant digit*? what is the input? what is the expected output? From my understanding, the most significant digit is the digit that is multiplied by the largest power of the base in a positional representation of a number, like the one in common use. E.g. the most significant digit of `1234` is `1`. So what is the meaning of the *most significant digit* when the input is a list of integer?

Comment: I think they're looking for an `itertools.groupby` solution that considers only adjacent digits...

Comment: SORRY i made a mistake there let me correct that , Thanks

Comment: 8 is the occurance of 3 , sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)) to group elements:

```
from itertools import groupby

num=[4,9,9,9,3,3,5,5,3]

out = []
for _, g in groupby( enumerate(num), lambda k: k[1] ):
    l = [*g]
    out.extend([l[0][0]] * len(l))

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8]
```

Comment: can it be done without importing modules because of time issues

Comment: @Anshul What do you mean by _time issues_? The time complexity of algorithm is O(n).

Comment: but the function iam running it in changes it to O(n^3) and values are in range 10^10

Comment: @Anshul Well, everything with O(n^3) where n=10^10 will be slow - a whole new algorithm or approach is needed in this case.

Comment: @Anshul Without any further info it's hard to help. But you could try to post your whole algorithm to Code Review https://codereview.stackexchange.com/?tags=python maybe they will help.